# Non-trivial element of $H_n(S^n)$ covers all of $S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have a question about singular homology of the $n$-sphere that I'm getting nowhere with:

**Prove the following:**

Any cycle $c$ that represents a non-trivial class in the $n$-th singular homology group $H_n(S^n)$ of the sphere covers all of $S^n$ (i.e. the union of the images of all singular $n$-simplices constituting $c$ is all of $S^n$).

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the simplices in question don't cover $S^n$, then as noted in Daniel Rust's answer, they lie in $S^n \setminus \{p\}$ for some point $p$,
and so induce an element of $H_n(S^n\setminus \{p\})$. 
Thus your original element lies in the image of the map
$H_n(S^n\setminus \{p\}) \to H_n(S^n).$  What can you say about this map?

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answers!

Comment: Now everything is clear, since $H_n(S^n \setminus \{p\}) = 0$  (because $S^n \setminus \{p\}$ is contractible)!

Comment: @TomBombadil exactly, so where must the homomorphism induced by the **inclusion map** send the class represented by the cycle?

Answer (score 3):

Hint, if all of the simplices miss at least one common point, then using a homeomorphism from the punctured sphere $S^n$ (punctured at the missed point) to the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, show that there is a homotopy from each simplex in the cycle to the constant map.

Another approach would be to use relative homology and the long exact sequence associated to the pair $(S^n, S^n\setminus\{p\})$.

Comment: What is stereographic projection?@DanielRust

Comment: @gaoxinge it's a homeomorphism from the punctured sphere to the euclidean space of the same dimension.